# Why can i increase the visibility of a overridden method in a subclass, is it not a security risk?

Tags: java, inheritance

If we consider this piece of code, is it not a security risk, if yes then why does java allow it?

```
class SomeApi
{
    void someImportantInnerApiMethod()
    {
    //some operation
    } 
}

class MaliciousUserClass extends SomeApi
{
    @Override
    public void someImportantInnerApiMethod()
    {
        super.someImportantInnerApiMethod();
        //inner api method now exposed
    } 
}
```

Comment: Visibility isn't about security.

Comment: "why" questions are overly broad, see Eric Lippert's answer on [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/217324)  I think the answer here is, because it doesn't hurt anything; if you want to nail down a method you can make it final.

Comment: @DonBranson suppose i have an api & some of the classes are are like the above class "SomeApi" & a user decides to extends & show all the inner protected / default methods then is it not a security issue ?

Comment: It would be if restricting visibility provided any security, but it provides absolutely zero security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access modifiers are not meant for security. You can call even a private method through reflection anyway. They are meant for encapsulation which shields from programming errors and enforces good programming style to a certain degree.

Even if you couldn't make overridden methods public, you could still do this:

```
class SomeApi
{
    void someImportantInnerApiMethod()
    {
    //some operation
    } 
}

class MaliciousUserClass extends SomeApi
{
    public void aMethodWithATotallyDifferentName()
    {
        // ... that still exposes that important inner API method!
        super.someImportantInnerApiMethod();
    } 
}
```

Since you can make it “accessible” in this way, the only thing that Java does is allow you to do exactly the same thing while keeping the method name, if you really want to do this. No harm done because you usually don't do this kind of thing accidentally.

It is also probably worth mentioning that package-private access is ridiculously easy to circumvent: unlike .Net's `internal`, you can really put your classes in the same package as another library you're using, and you're free to call package-private methods! Say, you declare your class to be a part of `javax.swing` package, now it can call Swing's package-private methods. So much for security. You don't even need inheritance and/or reflection.

Comment: I realize this was the most stupid question ever asked ! Thanks for pointing it out so clearly.

Comment: I would not say it is a stupid question, while I never thought of it as an issue, I did enjoy reading Sergey's response.
Plus don't they say there is no such thing as a stupid question.