# Override internal method in another package

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have a base class like following.

```kotlin
package somePackage

open class Base {
    internal open fun foo() {
        println("base-foo")
    }
}
```

Shouldn't I only be able to call the internal method if in same package as `Base`?

Why does the following work?

```kotlin
package otherPackage

class SubClass : Base()

fun main() {
    SubClass().xpto()
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024043/why-can-i-increase-the-visibility-of-a-overridden-method-in-a-subclass-is-it-no) it is possible to increase the visibility of a method. Although I'm not doing that, since I'm not overriding the method. If I do something like the following I understand but without overriding why does it allow me to call the internal method?

```kotlin
class SubClass : Base() {
    override fun xpto() {
        super.xpto()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`internal` visibility in Kotlin isn't the same as `package` visibility in Java. `internal` means that the element is visible to the code inside the same module, where module is described as the code compiled together, e.g. a subproject/module in Gradle/Maven. This is explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#modules